# Update the class attribute value

Tags: python

I met a problem with call the value from one class into a new iterative loop outside of that class. The code is shown below: (data and newdata are vectors)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, k, tol=0.0001, max_iter=300):
        self.k = k
        self.tol = tol
        self.max_iter = max_iter

    def fit(self, data):

        self.centroids = {}

        for i in range(self.k):
            self.centroids[i] = data[i+50]

        for i in range(self.max_iter):
            self.classifications = {}

            for i in range(self.k):
                self.classifications[i] = []

            for featureset in data:
                distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
                classification = distances.index(min(distances))
                self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)
            prev_centroids = dict(self.centroids)

            for classification in self.classifications:
                self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification], axis=0)

            optimized = True

            for c in self.centroids:
                original_centroid = prev_centroids[c]
                current_centroid = self.centroids[c]
                if np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0) > self.tol:
                    #print(np.sum((current_centroid - original_centroid) / original_centroid * 100.0))
                    optimized = False

            if optimized:
                break
            
    def cluster_labels(self,data):
        cluster_labels = []
        for featureset in data:
            distances=[np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
            cluster_labels.append(distances.index(min(distances)))
        return cluster_labels

    def predict(self, data):
        distances = [np.linalg.norm(data - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
        classification = distances.index(min(distances))
        return classification

    def update(self, new_data, delta):
        for featureset in new_data:
            distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]

            if min(distances) < delta:
                classification = distances.index(min(distances))
                self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)
                self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification], axis=0)
                
            else:
                self.centroids[self.k] = featureset
                self.classifications[self.k] = []
                self.classifications[self.k].append(featureset)   
                self.k = self.k + 1
                k = self.k
        print (k)
        return k

class Recorder:
    def __init__(rec):
        rec.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        rec.stream = rec.p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16, channels = 1, rate = 44100, input = True, input_device_index = 2, frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    def write():
        a = A(k=3)
        a.fit(data)
        k=a.update(newdata,20)

for num in range(1,100):
rec.Recorder()
rec.write()
```

Initially, I want to set k =3. And then, the value of k should be updated with `k=a.update(newdata,20)` However,now for every running, the value of K is staying at 3. And if I set k = 3 outside of the classes it always shows the error :

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'k' referenced before assignment
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: please give a useful example so that one can test the problem.

Comment: is your `else` statement even being reached?

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, for every time reached the else condition, the k automatically reset to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this function:

```
def update(self, new_data, delta):
    for featureset in new_data:
        distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]

        if min(distances) < delta:
            classification = distances.index(min(distances))
            self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)
            self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification], axis=0)
            
        else:
            self.centroids[self.k] = featureset
            self.classifications[self.k] = []
            self.classifications[self.k].append(featureset)   
            self.k = self.k + 1
            k = self.k
```

You are only setting the "k" value inside the "else" block. Leaving out anything unrelated it looks like this:

```
def update(self, new_data, delta):
    for featureset in new_data:
        ...
        if min(distances) < delta:
            ...
        else:
            ...
            k = self.k
    print (k)  # <-- error here
    return k  # <-- error here
```

In the case where `min(dinstances) >= delta`, `k` will not be set and you will get the error you report.

You have two options:

- Add a `k = ...` line into the if-block where `min(distances) < delta`
- Add a `k = ...` line *just above* the if-block (still inside the for-block) to set a "default" value for `k`

On review it is also possible that you just need to return `self.k` instead of just `k`.

Comment: But what I want to achieve is to remain the value of k `if min(distances) < delta:`, and update k for else condition

Comment: And the thing is that for every time calling the class A, the value of k remains the value of 3 although I set k = self.k in else condition. And I am sure the else condition is running when entering newdata. So, the problem is that k is always equal to 3 for each new iteration

Comment: The traceback you get doesn't lie. There is *some* part of your code which makes you enter the "if" block. The solution remains the same. You need to set the value of k before accessing it. If you want to keep "k" always the same you need to introduce a  new variable to modify in the "update()" function. But it still needs to be set to a value before you are using it.

Comment: It seems like I was confused with the reset of the k for each iteration. Unfortunately, I cannot upload all codes, which is too long. But thanks anyway.